Using VideoTexture with ShaderMaterial
I'm currently trying to implement a scroll effect with THREE.js that meets the following conditions.

When the page is loaded the three element should be scaled down to 0.3.
When the page is scrolled down, the three element should get bigger and the edges should bulge as seen below

When the page is scrolled up, the three element should get smaller and the edges should dip inwards as seen below

The Three element should show a video that is not distorted in any way and is good quality
Ideally the  rest of the page content can be seen behind the video, but I'm not sure if there's a way to make the canvas itself transparent or put HTML into the THREE scene

The problems I've been having are as follows

The original code was edited from a react three fiber tutorial, but I'm trying to use normal three since I'm going to be porting this into a Webflow site. When I finished translating the code I had to normal three.js, my result looked like this:

When I converted it to a video I had a similar problem as seen below:

I also notice that the shader is affecting my plane geometry and is cut off when the plane bulges past the container. Is there a way to conform the canvas to fit the plane geometry or place the bulge/dip shader code on the canvas?

Here is the react three fiber code for reference:
Model.jsx
import React, { useRef, Suspense } from 'react'
import { useControls } from 'leva';
import { fragment, vertex } from './Shader';
import { useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { useTexture, useAspect, useVideoTexture } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { transform } from "framer-motion"

export default function Model({scrollProgress}) {

const image = useRef();
const texture = useTexture("/images/car.jpg")
const { width, height } = texture.image;
const { viewport } = useThree();
const scale = useAspect(
    width,
    height,
    0.3
)

const [oldScrollProgress, setOldScrollProgress] = React.useState(0);
const [currentAnimation, setCurrentAnimation] = React.useState("bulge");

const activateBulge = () => {
    setCurrentAnimation("bulge");
}

const activateDip = () => {
    setCurrentAnimation("dip");
}

const activateNormal = () => {
    setCurrentAnimation("normal");
}

const { amplitude, waveLength } = useControls({
    amplitude: { value: 0.5, min: 0, max: 2, step: 0.1 },
    waveLength: { value: 3, min: 0, max: 20, step: 0.5 },
})

const uniforms = useRef({
    uTime: { value: 0 },
    uAmplitude: { value: amplitude },
    uWaveLength: { value: waveLength },
    uDirection: { value: 0 },
    uTexture: { value: texture },
    vUvScale: { value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
})

useFrame( () => {
    //scale image based on progress of the scroll
    const scaleX = transform(scrollProgress.get(), [0, 1], [scale[0], viewport.width])
    const scaleY = transform(scrollProgress.get(), [0, 1], [scale[1], viewport.height])
    image.current.scale.x = scaleX;
    image.current.scale.y = scaleY;

    //Adjust texture to new scale
    const scaleRatio = scaleX / scaleY;
    const aspectRatio = width / height
    //scale texture inside shader
   image.current.material.uniforms.vUvScale.value.set(1, aspectRatio / scaleRatio)

    //animate wave based on progress of the scroll
    const modifiedAmplitude = transform(scrollProgress.get(), [0, 1], [amplitude, 0])

    image.current.material.uniforms.uTime.value += 0.04;
    image.current.material.uniforms.uAmplitude.value = modifiedAmplitude
    image.current.material.uniforms.uWaveLength.value = waveLength;

    //determine direction of the scroll
    if (currentAnimation == "none") {
        if(scrollProgress.get() > oldScrollProgress){
            activateBulge();
        } else if(scrollProgress.get() < oldScrollProgress){
            activateDip();
        } else {
            activateNormal();
        }
    }

    if (currentAnimation == "bulge") {
        if (image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value >= 1) {
            setCurrentAnimation("none");
            setTimeout(() => {
                activateNormal();
            }, 300);
        } else {
            image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value += 0.05;
        }
    } else if (currentAnimation == "dip") {
        if (image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value <= -1) {
            setCurrentAnimation("none");
            setTimeout(() => {
                activateNormal();
            }, 300);
        } else {
            image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value += -0.05;
        }
    } else if (currentAnimation == "normal") {
        if (image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value < 0.01 && image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value > -0.01) {
            setCurrentAnimation("none");
        } else {
            image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value += (image.current.material.uniforms.uDirection.value > 0) ? -0.05 : 0.05;
        }
        
    }

    setOldScrollProgress(scrollProgress.get());

})

return (
    <mesh ref={image} scale={scale}>
        <planeGeometry args={[1, 1, 15, 15]}/>
        <shaderMaterial
            wireframe={false} 
            fragmentShader={fragment}
            vertexShader={vertex}
            uniforms={uniforms.current}
        />
    </mesh>
  )
}

Shader.js
export const vertex = `
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform float uAmplitude;
uniform float uWaveLength;
uniform float uDirection; // Add the int variable
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vec3 newPosition = position;
    float wave = uAmplitude * sin(abs(position.x + position.y) * uWaveLength) / 2.0;
    newPosition.z = position.z + (wave * uDirection);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
}

`
export const fragment = `
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform vec2 vUvScale;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = (vUv - 0.5) * vUvScale + 0.5;
    vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, uv);
    gl_FragColor = color;  
}
`

And here is my translated react-free implementation:
main.ts
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'

const vertex = `
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform float uAmplitude;
uniform float uWaveLength;
uniform float uDirection; // Add the int variable
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vec3 newPosition = position;
    float wave = uAmplitude * sin(abs(position.x + position.y) * uWaveLength) / 2.0;
    newPosition.z = position.z + (wave * uDirection);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
  }
`

const fragment = `
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform vec2 vUvScale;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = (vUv - 0.5) * vUvScale + 0.5;
    vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, uv);
    gl_FragColor = color;  
}
`

let oldScrollProgress = 0, currentAnimation = "none";

const getScrollProgress = () => {
  const scroll = window.scrollY;
  const height = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  return scroll / height;
}

const activateBulge = () => {
  currentAnimation = "bulge";
}

const activateDip = () => {
  currentAnimation = "dip";
}

const activateNormal = () => {
  currentAnimation = "normal";
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('webgl-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

const video = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLVideoElement;
const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
// const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/car.jpg');
video.play();
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 15, 15);
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  wireframe: false,
    uniforms: {
        uTime: { value: 0.0 },
    uAmplitude: { value: 0.5 },
    uWaveLength: { value: 3.0 },
    uDirection: { value: 0.0 },
    uTexture: { value: texture },
    vUvScale: { value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
    },

    vertexShader: vertex,
  fragmentShader: fragment

} );

const aspectRatio = (window.innerWidth - 50) / (window.innerHeight - 50);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 1;

function animate() {
  //scale image based on progress of the scroll
  const scrollProgress = getScrollProgress();
  const scale = 0.3 + (scrollProgress * 0.7);
  canvas.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;

  //scale texture inside shader
  material.uniforms.vUvScale.value.set(1, aspectRatio)

  //animate wave based on progress of the scroll
  let modifiedAmplitude = 0.1;

  material.uniforms.uAmplitude.value = modifiedAmplitude;

  //determine direction of the scroll
  if (currentAnimation == "none") {
      if(getScrollProgress() > oldScrollProgress){
          activateBulge();
      } else if(getScrollProgress() < oldScrollProgress){
          activateDip();
      } else {
          activateNormal();
      }
  }

  if (currentAnimation == "bulge") {
      if (material.uniforms.uDirection.value >= 1) {
          currentAnimation = "none";
          setTimeout(() => {
              activateNormal();
          }, 300);
      }
      material.uniforms.uDirection.value += 0.05;
  } else if (currentAnimation == "dip") {
      if (material.uniforms.uDirection.value <= -1) {
          currentAnimation = "none";
          setTimeout(() => {
              activateNormal();
          }, 300);
      }
      material.uniforms.uDirection.value += -0.05;
  } else if (currentAnimation == "normal") {
      if (material.uniforms.uDirection.value < 0.01 && material.uniforms.uDirection.value > -0.01) {
          currentAnimation = "none";
      } else {
          material.uniforms.uDirection.value += (material.uniforms.uDirection.value > 0) ? -0.05 : 0.05;
      }
      
  }

  oldScrollProgress = getScrollProgress();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Three.js TypeScript Tutorials by Sean Bradley : https://sbcode.net/threejs</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <video id="video" playsinline webkit-playsinline muted loop autoplay width="320" height="240" src="videos/LZShowreel.mp4" style="display: none;"></video>
    <canvas id="webgl-canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>

style.css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 300vh;
}

#webgl-canvas {
  /* background-color: transparent; */
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
}

